# word 2013 VBA / Macro crashes

Tags: vba, ms-word, windows-10, word-2013

Word 2013 crashes when running a VBA/macro on a document that has comments section enabled.  The macro searches for a character and replaces it with "" (blank) in the comments section and main document.  This is done using `Selection.Find.Execute` API.  When there is no comments section or no mark up is selected, Word doesn't crash.

This is on Windows 10 and word 2013. The macro works well in Word 2007 and Windows 7.

Reproducible steps:

1. Create a simple document with one text and add comment.
2. Insert the sample comment text as below: (add vertically like: A : & (enter) and so on)

   ```
   A: & B: & C: & D: & E: & F: & G: & H: & I: & J: & K: & L: & M: & N: &
   ```
3. Create macro:

   ```
   Sub Test_Macro()
       ActiveWindow.View.SplitSpecial = wdPaneComments
       With Selection.Find
               .Text = "&"
               .Replacement.Text = ""
               .Forward = True
               .Wrap = wdFindStop
               .Format = False
               .MatchCase = False
               .MatchWholeWord = False
               .MatchWildcards = False
               .MatchSoundsLike = False
               .MatchAllWordForms = False
       End With

       Selection.HomeKey unit:=wdStory

       If Selection.Find.Execute = True Then
          'We found the slash.  Delete it.
           Selection.TypeBackspace
       End If

   End Sub
   ```
4. Execute the Macro (`&` will be cleared).  Keep on executing again; Word will crash 2-3 times out of 10. (update the comment text accordingly, when all `&`s are cleared).

Comment: Exactly what is the error message you're getting, and can we see the faulty line of code and a bit of surrounding context?

Comment: word crashes. There's no error message as such. when we look at eventviewer, the stacktrace shows at wwlib.dll.  Here is the faulty line of code:                                                                                                          ' Go to the top of the document
    Selection.HomeKey unit:=wdStory

    If Selection.Find.Execute = True Then 'Word crashes here..
              Selection.TypeBackspace

Comment: word crashes at selection.find.execute; when i change the logic with some custom logic, word 2013 doesn't crash.  need to know if any micorosoft update has to be installed or is it a bug?

Comment: The most likely cause being the *some custom logic* part, it's very hard to tell (read: impossible) without knowing more about exactly what you're trying to accomplish that Word doesn't like.

Comment: let me re-clarify: macro code with selection.find.execute has been there for years and it has been working fine till word 2007. now with the same macro code crashes often in word 2013. hence changing the logic (of search and replace a character in comments section) doesn't crash. but would like to know why the word 2013 crashes at selection.find.execute

Comment: If you don't include steps to reproduce the problem (including code) it's impossible for anyone to help you. Please read the guidelines on asking questions on this site in the [help].

Comment: @balaji: I have to second that Cindy already said. Show us a sample document and tell us the steps to reproduce the problem. Then we might able to help. Otherwise there are just too many options. This could be a Word problem, an issue with your environment, with specific kinds of documents, etc.

Comment: Balaji, welcome to Stack Overflow, and good job upgrading your post in response to feedback.  I am having buggy behavior while editing the post.  I apologize for any confusion and I hope the current result is acceptable.  I wish the code block would format correctly, but there seems to be a glitch.

Comment: Is anyone able to reproduce the same issue?  (in win 10 OS and Word 2013)

Comment: @Smandoli The code block needs eight leading spaces instead of four.  That is because the code blocks are inside a bulleted list, and each block is considered to belong to a list item.  Buried [here](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-and-highlighting-code-blocks/): "To preserve your formatting within a list, make sure to indent non-fenced code blocks by eight spaces."

Answer (score 0):

I do not see a question in your text, so I can not answer, but I can confirm that Microsoft Word 2013 crashes on `ActiveDocument.Content.Find.Execute`. I routinely had to work around this by manually exercising the Replace dialog before executing the macro. This worked (almost) every time.
Now I found [this post](https://devwrench.wordpress.com/2016/08/19/fix-word-vba-crash-wdreplaceall/) that says that it has something to do with Execute running with an empty undo record. I was able to work around this issue by inserting a line of code that adds some text to the last paragraph of the document right after the undo record is created.